# Python - Created number of nested folders

Tags: python, directory, creation

I am trying to create a number of nested folders in python.

Objective: 
1) Ask user for a number (Let us say 3)
2) Create 3 folders.
3) Inside each folder, there should be 3 folders.
This nesting should be done 3 times.

Example:

```
Folder1
```

> Folder1
>   Folder2
>   Folder3
>
> > Folder1
> >     Folder2
> >     Folder3
> >
> > > Folder1
> > >       Folder2
> > >       Folder3

```
Folder2
```

> Folder1
>   Folder2
>   Folder3
>
> > Folder1
> >     Folder2
> >     Folder3
> >
> > > Folder1
> > >       Folder2
> > >       Folder3

```
Folder3
```

> Folder1
>   Folder2
>   Folder3
>
> > Folder1
> >     Folder2
> >     Folder3
> >
> > > Folder1
> > >       Folder2
> > >       Folder3

This is my current code:

```
import os
i = 0
num = 0
while i<17:
    num+=1
    name="Python"+ str(num)
    i+=1
```

This is only for creating the first set of folders (I have taken 17).
Help would be much appreciated.

(I am running Windows)

**EDIT:**

For a more clearer example : http://s9.postimg.org/sehux992n/20141228_201038.jpg

(Taking 3 as the user input)

From the image, we can see that there are 3 layers.

Comment: Sounds tailor-made for a recursive function.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to continue after this

Comment: so the user enters 1 number or 2?

Comment: The user enters can number they like (less than 50, since it is an exponential function).

Comment: As in the example, they are to be named like: Folder1, Folder2 .....

Answer (score 1):

Partial code, feel free to fill in the blanks:

```
def recursive_make_folders(path, width, depth):
    for i in range(1, width + 1):
        folder_name = make_folder_name(i)
        make_folder(path + folder_name)
        if depth > 1:
            recursive_make_folders(path + folder_name, width, depth - 1)
```

Keep in mind, this will create `width ** depth` folders, which can be a very large number, especially as `depth` increases.

**Edit:**

- where I show `path + folder_name`, you will need to actually use `os.path.join(path, folder_name)`
- `make_folder` should become `os.mkdir`
- if you want the code to run in the current directory, you can use `"."` as the initial path

Comment: While entering the path, Python returns an invalid syntax error. (For the drive letter). Suppose I wanted to create it in the current directory?

Comment: What is `make_folder_name` ?

Comment: I have added a link that better explains the nesting

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have subdirectories with the same names  inside the folder. If you want to add input * input directories with different names:

```
import os

inp = int(raw_input())

folders = [("Folder{}".format(i)) for i in xrange(1,inp+1)]
for dr in xrange(1,inp+1):
    os.makedirs("Folder{}".format(dr))
for fold in folders:
    os.chdir(fold)
    for i in xrange(1, inp*inp+1):
        os.makedirs("Folder{}".format(i))
    os.chdir("..")
```

Maybe this is closer to what you want:

```
import os

inp = int(raw_input())

folders = [("Folder{}".format(i)) for i in xrange(1, inp+1)]
for fold in folders:
    os.makedirs(fold)
    os.chdir(fold)
    for fold in folders:
        os.mkdir(fold)
        os.chdir(fold)
        for fold in folders:
            os.mkdir(fold)
        os.chdir("..")
    os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB, I am a little unsure of your nesting requirement as I said in my comment, can you add a single complete folder tree  when the input is 3. Once I can understand exactly what you mean it is just a matter of nesting a for loop

Comment: I have added a link that better explains the nesting